# FFmpeg - downmixing FLAC 6.1 to AAC 5.1

Tags: ffmpeg, aac, flac

I can't seem to figure out how to do this. I've been staring at these commands:
https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/AudioChannelManipulation

But to no avail. It's a tad above my level, sadly. Here's the ffmpeg -i output for the video in question:

```
ffmpeg version N-64012-g61df081 Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Jun 16 2014 22:01:59 with gcc 4.8.3 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex--enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-decklink --enable-zlib
  libavutil      52. 89.100 / 52. 89.100
  libavcodec     55. 67.100 / 55. 67.100
  libavformat    55. 43.100 / 55. 43.100
  libavdevice    55. 13.101 / 55. 13.101
  libavfilter     4.  8.100 /  4.  8.100
  libswscale      2.  6.100 /  2.  6.100
  libswresample   0. 19.100 /  0. 19.100
  libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
Input #0, matroska,webm, from '[Coalgirls]_Spirited_Away_(1920x1038_Blu-ray_FLAC)_[92372194].mkv':
  Metadata:
    title           : Spirited Away
    encoder         : libebml v1.3.0 + libmatroska v1.4.0
    creation_time   : 2014-07-03 01:32:13
  Duration: 02:04:32.29, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 15972 kb/s
    Chapter #0.0: start 0.000000, end 99.099000
    Metadata:
      title           : 00:00:00.000
    Chapter #0.1: start 99.099000, end 196.238000
    Metadata:
      title           : 00:01:39.099
    Chapter #0.2: start 196.238000, end 443.526000
    Metadata:
      title           : 00:03:16.238
    Chapter #0.3: start 443.526000, end 645.395000
    Metadata:
      title           : 00:07:23.526
    Chapter #0.4: start 645.395000, end 1023.022000
    Metadata:
      title           : 00:10:45.395
    Chapter #0.5: start 1023.022000, end 1368.534000
    Metadata:
      title           : 00:17:03.022
    Chapter #0.6: start 1368.534000, end 1716.048000
    Metadata:
      title           : 00:22:48.534
    Chapter #0.7: start 1716.048000, end 2008.173000
    Metadata:
      title           : 00:28:36.048
    Chapter #0.8: start 2008.173000, end 2301.674000
    Metadata:
      title           : 00:33:28.173
    Chapter #0.9: start 2301.674000, end 2651.816000
    Metadata:
      title           : 00:38:21.674
    Chapter #0.10: start 2651.816000, end 2906.821000
    Metadata:
      title           : 00:44:11.816
    Chapter #0.11: start 2906.821000, end 3271.351000
    Metadata:
      title           : 00:48:26.821
    Chapter #0.12: start 3271.351000, end 3729.017000
    Metadata:
      title           : 00:54:31.351
    Chapter #0.13: start 3729.017000, end 4091.587000
    Metadata:
      title           : 01:02:09.017
    Chapter #0.14: start 4091.587000, end 4476.847000
    Metadata:
      title           : 01:08:11.587
    Chapter #0.15: start 4476.847000, end 4750.579000
    Metadata:
      title           : 01:14:36.847
    Chapter #0.16: start 4750.579000, end 5139.760000
    Metadata:
      title           : 01:19:10.579
    Chapter #0.17: start 5139.760000, end 5478.890000
    Metadata:
      title           : 01:25:39.760
    Chapter #0.18: start 5478.890000, end 5853.806000
    Metadata:
      title           : 01:31:18.890
    Chapter #0.19: start 5853.806000, end 6318.937000
    Metadata:
      title           : 01:37:33.806
    Chapter #0.20: start 6318.937000, end 6625.118000
    Metadata:
      title           : 01:45:18.937
    Chapter #0.21: start 6625.118000, end 6771.098000
    Metadata:
      title           : 01:50:25.118
    Chapter #0.22: start 6771.098000, end 6914.199000
    Metadata:
      title           : 01:52:51.098
    Chapter #0.23: start 6914.199000, end 7253.580000
    Metadata:
      title           : 01:55:14.199
    Chapter #0.24: start 7253.580000, end 7472.288000
    Metadata:
      title           : 02:00:53.580
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High 10), yuv420p10le(tv, bt709), 1920x1038, SAR 1:1 DAR 320:173, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 1k tbn, 47.95 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      title           : Spirited Away
    Stream #0:1(jpn): Audio: flac, 48000 Hz, 6.1, s32 (default)
    Metadata:
      title           : 6.1 FLAC
    Stream #0:2(eng): Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, 5.1(side), fltp, 448 kb/s
    Metadata:
      title           : 5.1 AC3
    Stream #0:3(fre): Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, 5.1(side), fltp, 448 kb/s
    Metadata:
      title           : 5.1 AC3
    Stream #0:4(ger): Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, 5.1(side), fltp, 448 kb/s
    Metadata:
      title           : 5.1 AC3
    Stream #0:5(fin): Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 192 kb/s
    Metadata:
      title           : 2.0 AC3
    Stream #0:6(kor): Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, 5.1(side), fltp, 448 kb/s
    Metadata:
      title           : 5.1 AC3
    Stream #0:7(chi): Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, 5.1(side), fltp, 448 kb/s
    Metadata:
      title           : 5.1 AC3
    Stream #0:8(chi): Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, 5.1(side), fltp, 448 kb/s
    Metadata:
      title           : 5.1 AC3
    Stream #0:9(eng): Subtitle: ssa (default)
    Metadata:
      title           : English
    Stream #0:10(fre): Subtitle: ssa
    Metadata:
      title           : French
    Stream #0:11(ger): Subtitle: ssa
    Metadata:
      title           : German
    Stream #0:12(eng): Subtitle: ssa
    Metadata:
      title           : Songs + Signs
    Stream #0:13: Attachment: ttf
    Metadata:
      filename        : MyriadPro-Regular.otf
      mimetype        : application/x-truetype-font
    Stream #0:14: Attachment: ttf
    Metadata:
      filename        : MyriadPro-SemiboldIt.otf
      mimetype        : application/x-truetype-font
    Stream #0:15: Attachment: ttf
    Metadata:
      filename        : Vesta-Bold.otf
      mimetype        : application/x-truetype-font
    Stream #0:16: Attachment: ttf
    Metadata:
      filename        : Vesta-Bold_2.otf
      mimetype        : application/x-truetype-font
    Stream #0:17: Attachment: ttf
    Metadata:
      filename        : AR CENA_0.TTF
      mimetype        : application/x-truetype-font
    Stream #0:18: Attachment: ttf
    Metadata:
      filename        : tahomabd.ttf
      mimetype        : application/x-truetype-font
    Stream #0:19: Attachment: ttf
    Metadata:
      filename        : palai.ttf
      mimetype        : application/x-truetype-font
    Stream #0:20: Attachment: ttf
    Metadata:
      filename        : pala.ttf
      mimetype        : application/x-truetype-font
```

As you can see, one of the streams is a FLAC 6.1 stream. I wanted to convert that to AAC, and I know how to do that, basically like this:

```
ffmpeg -i "input.mkv" -codec:v copy -codec:a aac -strict -2 -b:a 320k -f matroska "output.mkv"
```

But apparently AAC doesn't support 6.1 audio:

```
...
[aac @ 03b26860] Unsupported number of channels: 7
Output #0, matroska, to 'd:\Movies\[Coalgirls]_Spirited_Away_(1920x1038_Blu-ray_FLAC)_[92372194].aac.mkv':
    Stream #0:0(jpn): Video: h264, yuv420p10le, 1920x1038 [SAR 1:1 DAR 320:173], q=2-31, 23.98 fps, 90k tbn, 1k tbc (default)
    Stream #0:1(jpn): Audio: aac, 0 channels, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc55.67.100 aac
    Stream #0:2(eng): Subtitle: ssa, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc55.67.100 ssa
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (flac (native) -> aac (aac))
  Stream #0:9 -> #0:2 (ssa (native) -> ssa (native))
Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:1 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
```

That's fine, so I wanted to downmix it to 5.1 and encode as AAC. But I can't seem to work out how to. Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Last I heard, the aac encoder for ffmpeg was considered experimental. It's usually recommended to either :

- Compile your own ffmpeg with the inclusion of libfdk_aac, which is the best AAC encoder for ffmpeg but isn't included due to licensing reasons (https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/AAC)
- Use NeroAacCodec, a free high quality aac encoder by nero. You can use ffmpeg to extract the FLAC track, convert it to wav and send it to NeroAacCodec

I can't guarantee you that either will support 6.1 in/5.1 out, but there's a big chance it'll work better than ffmpeg's built-in aac encoder.

Comment: The aac encoder is not neccesarily the problem. I've encoded to 5.1 AAC before and it worked perfectly. The problem seems to be that the source is 6.1 FLAC while I want it to become 5.1. So the fact that I eventually want it to encode to AAC, is trivial - it could be FLAC just as well. So I guess what I need is a way to go from 6.1 to 5.1, regardless of codecs.

Comment: Actually I was able just now to do it by adding `-ac 6` to the command line, but I'm not quite sure if this produces a proper downmix, or if ffmpeg simply discards on of the channels...

Comment: @Martijn according to the audio channel manipulation article you linked in your question, "-ac 6" should produce a proper downmix, if you do not specify an explicit new channel mapping (which would give you the opportunity to leave out a channel). However, when downmixing, you should always consider to also add the option "-rematrix_maxval 1" to avoid clipping (through the addition of channels they may become too loud otherwise).